# check whether text in textbox matches a certain word in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

i would like to check whether the text in a text box matches a certain string. I have used an action listener, when the button is pressed it will check whether the text in the text box matches a certain word.

Thanks

This is what i have tried:

```
enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (txtbox.getText() == "cat") {
            txtbox.setText("correct");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use `if (txtbox.getText().equals("cat"))`

Answer (score 1):

***==*** is used to compare references and ***equals*** method (present in ***Object*** class) is used to compare the value of the objects. So in your case since you want to compare the value so consider using equals like

```
String myString ="cat";
if(myString.equals("cat")){
 //do something    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**==** is used to check the reference.

**equals** is used to check the actual content at of the objects.

Below code shows how to update the `JTextField`.

```
final JTextField textField = new JTextField("cat");
JButton button = new JButton("Click");
// Code
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(textField.getText().equals("cat")) {
                    textField.setText("Changes");
                } else {
                    textField.setText("Already Changed");
                }
            }
        });
```